# Make NSArray out of each word in text file

Tags: nsarray

So what I want to accomplish is to make a NSArray out of a txt file and each word would be an object in that array. Below is some code that doesn't work. No crashes but doesn't do anything.

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"badwords" ofType:@"txt"];
if (filePath) {
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"badwords.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

lines is a NSArray.

Any reason why this shouldn't work? Each word is separated by a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good reason: `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: ...]` should be taking the `filePath` you derived in the preceding statement as an argument and *not* `@"badwords.txt"`, the literal string filename. That's the whole reason for deriving the `filePath` in the first line -- you then want to use it in the second.

In other words I'm simply saying you should change this:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"badwords.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

to this:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? How would I fix it then?

Comment: I've amended the original answer to provide more clarity.